# Securestring and other ways to hiding string data

Tags: c#-4.0, securestring

I recently came across SecureString, but as most of you know, you would be unable to use it because most of the functions you want to use accept string as parameter, not SecureString.

How to use SecureString then?

If I need to pass string across multiple programs, is it safer to byte array compared to plain string if string is sensitive information?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sensitive, encrypt it.

See the [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace.

There are many encryption algorithms supported, but is impossible to suggest to you which one to use, as the specific security requirements for your situation are not known.

Comment: so I shouldn't pass plain strings between programs on the same computer?

Comment: @TPR - It is only a problem if someone has access to the computer memory. `SecureString` will help with memory dumps.